# How would I go about migrating a database to a cloud service?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

folks. I'm handling some large amount of data on pandas dataframes, but it´s getting slow and I need to keep updating the tables. So I was thinking about saving everything on a database locally on my computer. For money reasons and unexperience with cloud services, I wanted to do it first on my computer and then online.
Is there a way to migrate from my computer to a Amazon service for example? And how would I do it?
I'm using MySQL Workbench.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you think the cloud will be faster or cheaper? It will be neither of those things.

Comment: You're asking if there's a way to import a MySQL database into RDS? Yes, see the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html).

Comment: Additional information request to improve current speed. 
any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
name; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.